# How do you say something is "in flux" in Classical Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

In English we have *in flux*, which you can use to say that something is in a state of change. How do you use an adjective that way in Latin? Could you use *fluxus* in ablative/accusative case with the preposition *in* but omit the noun, or would a gerundive with the verb *fluo* make more sense?

Some other examples of this format in English:

In play,
In demand,
In motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start might be the famous hexameter verse:

> *Tempora mutantur nos et mutamur in illis.*
> Times are changing and we are changing with them.

I am not sure about *fluere*, but at least *mutari* makes an idiomatic wording for "in a state of change".
So, if something is in a state of change, I'd suggest saying simply *(aliquid) mutatur*.

If you need an adjective instead of a verb, another (part of a) hexameter line to look at would be:

> *Varium et mutabile semper femina.*
> A woman is always changing.

Together with the verb *mutari*, this suggests that *mutabilis* would fit.
As always, things depend on context, but I offer this as a starting point.

Is there a problem not solved by a suitable line of hexameter?

Comment: If it can't be said in hexameter... No, you should always try to say it in hexameter.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: In "varium et mutabile semper femina" why use two adjectives and why are these neuter?

Comment: @tony You can read the neuter as "a woman is a changing thing", so that the adjectives don't refer directly to *femina*. It's not unusual in any poetry to use a surprising amount of adjectives, and the two here are not exactly synonymous. For simplicity I conflated them to one adjective in English.